# Are these duplicates?

Tags: support, exact-duplicates, specific-question

Recently I have asked a question I wasn't able to find already asked: [How to add behavior-based onclick to ajax-enabled Form API button?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/91376/16495)

Now, using comments by [Beebee](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/5284/beebee) I found a working solution. Also, thanks to his comments, I get to know about older similar question: [Listen to AJAX complete event from a behavior](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/32924/16495)

Now, they are similar for sure. But are they duplicates? If so, which one should get closed? I dare to shamelessly say that it appears I've put a bit more effort in my question. And the answer to the older one simply does not work for me.

Comment: I think users can ask same questions older than 6 month and no need to close.

Comment: @Bala Nope, there is no time limit. And I don't think there should be. Stack network is designed to be a knowledge repository. But I think these are different, even if similar. But Beebee called them dupes. I don't mind if they will get closed, if most of you thinks they are. I just want some opinions on this.

Comment: Molot FYI http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/88200/how-to-increase-the-speed-of-exposed-autocomplete-field-in-views-using-drupal-6 same condition here, but marked as duplicate by you and MPD disagreed. I think it depends on  person to person and expecting opinion may be looks broad.

Comment: @Bala but MPD also provided different solution, and your acceptance proved I was wrong ;) Here we have quite opposite, for Paul Sheldrake listening for AJAX complete was a goal he put in his question. For me it was an answer. So in your case goals looked similar, solutions didn't, here goals are different, but solutions are similar.

Comment: +1 for having asked on meta about your how question.

Comment: @Mołot +1 this question shows your sinciarity to DA, great!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not say they are duplicates, since the other question doesn't even show any code. The other question is asking how to achieve something, while you are saying your code doesn't work and you want to know why, or how to fix it.

That is the important difference that cannot be forgetten. The questions are so different that the only thing they have in common is that they are about Drupal AJAX.

Comment: Thank you. It was thin line, especially since duplicates are no longer expected to be "exact" and this word got removed from close reason.

Comment: Still, _duplicates_ means more than "both the questions are about AJAX."

Comment: But I'm not arguing, I was just explaining the source of my doubts.

Comment: I understood; I just meant that removing that word doesn't mean that closing loosely related question is now acceptable.